# Executing cURL command in groovy properly

Tags: json, curl, groovy, escaping, jira

I want to use a cURL command for sending JSON data to a server via POST. It's for creating a JIRA issue.

I am using groovy code for generating those commands. However the created cURL commands work fine and does exactly what I want if I execute it in the console. It doesn't work if I execute it in groovy though.

Here is the groovy code where I try to execute the cURL command:

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder.fields {
    /* setting up JSON Builder */
}

String curlStr = "curl -D- -u user:pwd -X POST --data \"${builder.toString().replace('"', "\\\"")}\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" ${BASE_URL}/rest/api/2/issue/"
Process response = curlStr.execute()
response.waitFor()
// printing error
print("response.error=${response.err.text}")
print("response=${response.text}")
// printing curl string
print("curlStr=${curlStr}")
```

The output is as follows:

```
response.error= % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: not curl: (6) Could not resolve host: set.\",\"description\" curl: (6) Could not resolve host: of curl: (6) Could not resolve host: an curl: (6) Could not resolve host: issue curl: (6) Could not resolve host: using curl: (6) Could not resolve host: project curl: (6) Could not resolve host: keys curl: (6) Could not resolve host: and curl: (6) Could not resolve host: issue curl: (6) Could not resolve host: type curl: (6) Could not resolve host: names curl: (6) Could not resolve host: using curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the curl: (6) Could not resolve host: REST curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 22 curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application 100 64 0 0 100 64 0 1974 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1974

response=HTTP/1.1 415 Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 11:47:58 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) X-AREQUESTID: 827x52078x1 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' X-ASEN: SEN-13974383 X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK X-ASESSIONID: 126fo6k X-AUSERNAME: user Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=9E8CEDF3CC7FC1BC41BD98A32771A0D0;path=/;HttpOnly Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BGEA-KKM0-ZLFV-1RQ2|db9e7165e3e35aff332231f690acea456d61fe25|lin;path=/ 

curlStr=curl -D- -u user:pwd -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"WW\"},\"summary\":\"Summary not set.\",\"description\":\"Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API.\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Issue name\"},\"customfield_14702\":[{\"key\":\"SM-480070\"}],\"customfield_14200\":[{\"key\":\"SM-255197\"}],\"customfield_14700\":[{\"key\":\"SM-255088\"}],\"customfield_14701\":[{\"key\":\"SM-255202\"}],\"customfield_14706\":\"2019-06-13T12:57:00.00+0200\",\"customfield_10403\":\"2019-06-13T13:47:59.130+0200\"}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://some.server.de/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Please note that I changed things like the username and password to protect sensitive data.

I am expecting that I screwed with the escaping of some characters in my command or groovy interpreting things different than I expect. How can I execute the command as it is in groovy properly?

Comment: Never-ever `"string".execute()`.  Use `["cmd", "arg", "..."].execute()`.  Groovy's execute on String splits on whitespace and does usually the wrong thing.  Also don't quote for the shell, if you don't use a shell.  The string you are using there might maybe work with `["sh", "-c", curlString].execute()` if you prefer to write the code like for a shell.

Comment: `-D-` looks odd too

Comment: @cfrick Your are right. I got it working with your solution.

Comment: @tim_yates I am using -D- because it's suggested in the JIRA documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/